# Issue with 2D Shrinkwrap (Circle onto Cross)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Howdy Blender Community,

I'm attempting to apply a shrinkwrap modifier (in Cycles) such that a circle mesh morphs into a cross mesh:

[image]

This works perfectly well when the target is a square, but when the target is the cross, this happens:

[image]

The circle collapses into a line. I have tried all three modes of shrinkwrap to no avail, and would be much obliged for any ideas as to how I might fix this.

My thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Make sure both shapes have a height and faces with area, so that *Shrinkwrap* modifier as normals on which to operate in.

Make sure you circle is big enough to encompass the whole cross.

Make sure your cross is high enough to cover all the circle height.

The point here is to guarantee all face normals encounter the other object operand. If you wish to have 2D shapes you can then after applyinf the modifier remove undesired faces and make them an edge wireframe only.

Change the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to *Project* mode, and the *Direction* to *Negative*. That should do it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your rapid response, @Duarte. This definitely resolves the issue in one sense. I am curious, though, why the shrinkwrap would work with the rectangular mesh, for example, and not with the cross mesh... I ask because my objects are semitransparent and adding the depth dimension changes how they render. Either way, you have my vote and appreciation!

Comment: My blind guess is that *Shrinkwrap* needs geometry to work Without actual faces it can't properly read shapes, and without face normals it can't compute a projection direction. As stated after converting to shapekeys you can then safely erase the faces and make it 2D